# How do I use Actionmailer to send daily emails with the Heroku production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actionmailer

Thank you for taking a look at this.

Heroku doesn't allow for cron tasks to be run directly from the app; you have to use their scheduler to set up cron jobs. The jobs I have written work just fine in development, but none of my users are receiving the emails in production.

**My code for my mailer:**

```
class PostsMailer < ActionMailer::Base

 default from: "christopher@scratchitoff.co"

  def daily_email(user)
    @user= user
    @posts = user.posts
    @url = "http://scratchitoff.co/lists"
    mail(to:@user.email, subject: 'Your active to-do items')
  end
```

end

**My view for my mailer:**

```
<h2>Hello <%= @user.name %></h2>
 Your active to-do Items:
 <ul>
   <% @posts.each do |post| %>
     <li><%= post.title %></li>
   <% end %>
 </ul>

 -sincerely, Christopher
```

**My rake tasks run by the scheduler:**

```
namespace :notifications do 
  desc " Daily posts email to users"
    task :daily_post_email => :environment do 
      users = User.all   
      users.each do |user|
        PostsMailer.daily_email(user)
      end
    end
  end
```

Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, I think you forgot the payload - try: `PostsMailer.daily_email(user).deliver`

Comment: @Christopher Bradford: did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score -1):

There're several ways to do that:
 - Cronjob
 - Do some cheat in rails config, create schedule.rb file in config directory. Then add the following lines:

```
every 1.day do
  runner "User.send_mail"
end
```

As, you can see. You need to define the send_mail method in the User model. It's just an example. Hope it help you.